# How do I set up my Core Data model when my objects have arbitrary property data?

Tags: objective-c, database, core-data, data-modeling, foundation

I'm struggling to figure out how to build a Core Data model to support the class structure I've created in my app.

My app has users, and I allow those users to log into the app using multiple different authentication methods. Each authentication method requires slightly different credentials and cred types. I've chosen to solve this by creating an abstract `AuthenticationSettings` base class, then subclass it with `FacebookAuthenticationSettings`, `TwitterAuthenticationSettings`, `MyWebsiteAuthenticationSettings`, etc.

My `User` class has a property `authSettings` (of type `AuthenticationSettings`), that stores an instance of one of the settings classes. Users are allowed only one auth method per user, so this works great.

The question is, how do I create a Core Data model for my users given that `authSettings` can have one of many object types stored to it?

- Do I create separate entities for each type of authentication and then create relationships between those entities and the user entity? This is strange because the data model doesn't enforce 1:1 auth method to user. When fetching users, I'd also have to fetch their corresponding auth methods.
- Do I just create my own serialization encoding of the auth creds and jam it into a string field on the user entity? This forces me to invent some encoding which feels especially messy if any future auth methods use fields that are difficult to serialize to string.
- Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to set up a Core Data entity hierarchy that parallels your class hierarchy. Create an abstract entity in Core Data called `AuthenticationSettings` and create a series of sub-entities for each authentication type. As with your `User` class property, create a relationship to `AuthenticationSettings`.

A simpler approach that sounds like it would meet your needs would be to make your various authentication classes conform to `NSCoding`, and then just store them in a single "transformable" (not string) field on the user entity. Core Data would then convert the authentication object to/from `NSData` automatically.

Comment: Perfect! I was unaware of the Transformable type.

Comment: In this instance, I would stay away from transformables.  Those are intended for custom data types, such as locations (coordinate pairs) or some other non-class-based structure.  If an authentication method is modeled as a distinct object type, it should be mirrored in Core Data.

Comment: @Avi not sure what you're getting at. This is the exact situation transformables were designed for. Transformable attributes only work on objects that conform to `NSCoding`, so "non class based" doesn't make sense.

Comment: We'd have to ask the Apple engineers to know who's right about intent, but I disagree.  Transformables are for things like encoding `CGRect` or `CGSize`.  Structures that are not classes.  Apple's example app encodes an image.  I think that anything which is modeled as an object should be reflected that way in Core Data.  Remember, Core Data is an object graph persistence layer.  If you have an object graph as your in-memory model, you should be persisting it as-is, or as close to it as Core Data permits.

Comment: I'd be most interested to see how you make `CGRect` conform to `NSCoding`.

Comment: Perhaps my examples are bad.  Still, if an object is modeled with properties that can be persisted directly, they should be.

Comment: No. It doesn't make sense to include the extra complexity in the Core Data model unless Core Data modeling is specifically relevant to the data. A one-to-one relationship to an object that is never used in fetching, predicates, that never has this relationship changed, etc, is a prime candidate for being saved as a transformable. You're recommending additional complexity for absolutely no benefit.